# Threejs - can you use circleBufferGeometry with Points material?

Tags: three.js, buffer-geometry

I am setting up a particle system in threejs by adapting the [buffer geometry drawcalls example](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_buffergeometry_drawcalls) in threejs. I want to create a series of points, but I want them to be round.

The [documentation for threejs points](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/objects/Points) says it accepts geometry or buffer geometry, but I also noticed there is a [circleBufferGeometry](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/geometries/CircleBufferGeometry). Can I use this?
 Or is there another way to make the points round besides using sprites? I'm not sure, but it seems like [loading an image for each particle](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_points_billboards.html) would cause a lot of unnecessary overhead.

So, in short, is there a more performant or simple way to make a particle system of round particles (spheres or discs) in threejs without sprites?

Comment: Hmmm, i think the accepted answer does not answer the question properly, or maybe some detail should be taken out / added from the question. You specifically ask to use `circleBufferGeometry` as the shape of the particle. It may not be obvious, but you ask first about points and the geometry it takes for *distribution* and then ask for *shapes* of the particles (mentioning geometry again). It's clear you're confusing these two concepts. So it's like two questions:

Comment: How can i make particles that appear round (shape)? How can i use `circleBufferGeometry` as a shape for a particle system? With the accepted answer you're possibly technically still using sprites, or at least billboards. Right now this looks to me "How can i do A" "Do B that looks like A" "Ok" :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to draw each "point"/"particle" as a geometric circle, you can use `THREE.InstancedBufferGeometry` or take a look at [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/three-instanced-mesh)

Answer (score 2):

The geometry of a `Points` object defines where the points exist in 3D space. It ***does not*** define the shape of the points. Points are also drawn as quads, so they're always going to be a square, though they don't have to appear that way.

Your first option is to (as you pointed out) load a texture for each point. I don't really see how this would introduce "a lot" of overhead, because the texture would only be loaded once, and would be applied to all points. But, I'm sure you have your reasons.

Your other option is to [create your own shader to draw the point as a circle](https://www.desultoryquest.com/blog/drawing-anti-aliased-circular-points-using-opengl-slash-webgl/). This method takes the point as a square, and discards any fragments (multiple fragments make up a pixel) outside the circle.

Comment: Thank you TheJim01 for your valuable answer. I have actually passed through the linked in past but left it unused because this is similar to using "SpriteMaterial" in three.js (i.e. no sense of orientation).
At-least when using SpriteMaterial, all "disks" are facing towards camera, but I guess I can give it a try with shader and try to rotate the points.

Comment: One request (If I may), can you give me a pointer on how to plug in rotation values (which are converted to a rotation matrix) in the shader?
In the mean time, I have implemented this [link](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/create-circular-planar-elements-from-points/12981/9?u=asif_ali) with InstancedMesh but that is just avoiding the inevitable.

Comment: @AsifAli I recommend creating a new question. That way anyone can answer, and everyone can benefit from the exchange.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions, I will create a new question and tag you.